# XAttribute maintain CR

Tags: c#

I have a KVP with the data I want to be in my XAttribute which looks like this;

```
var kvpAttribute = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("rsaKey", @"----RSAKEY----
AWEACAWE123213AWEAWECAWE!AWEAWE
AWEAWEAWEAWEAWEQEAWEAWHYTAWEAAA
----END RSA KEY ----");
```

(removed actual key)

And I'm trying to write this to an XML file. The program that reads this XML requires the key to be formatted as is from the file (with CR between lines), when writing this key using;

```
var element = new XElement("Blah");
var attribute = new XAttribute("key", kvpAttribute.Key);
var attribute2 = new XAttribute("value", kvpAttribute.Value);
```

and then saving the XDocument using XDocument.Save(FolderPath, FileName) I get the output in my XML;

```
<add value="----RSAKEY---&#xD;&#xA;AWEACAWE123213AWEAWECAWE!AWEAWE&#xD;&#xA;AWEAWEAWEAWEAWEQEAWEAWHYTAWEAAA&#xD;&#xA;----END RSA KEY ----" key="rsaKey"/>
```

(Removed actual key again)

As you can see the CR's are replaced with CR/LF (&#xD ;&#xA ;).

Is there a way to maintain the formatting from the KVP accross into the XML file itself?

Comment: Your first piece of code doesn't compile, because it's not a verbatim string literal. If it *were* a verbatim string literal, it might have CRs or it might have CR/LF depending on the source file format, which we can't really tell.

Comment: @DaisyShipton You're right sorry, I missed it out I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect this is because your string *actually* has CR/LF to start with.

Assuming your code actually uses a verbatim string literal like this:

```
// Note the @
var kvpAttribute = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("rsaKey", @"----RSAKEY----
AWEACAWE123213AWEAWECAWE!AWEAWE
AWEAWEAWEAWEAWEQEAWEAWHYTAWEAAA
----END RSA KEY ----");
```

... the line endings of the source file will be propagated into the literal.

The easiest way to "fix" this is just to replace "\r\n" with "\r" in the string:

```
string rsaKey = @"----RSAKEY----
AWEACAWE123213AWEAWECAWE!AWEAWE
AWEAWEAWEAWEAWEQEAWEAWHYTAWEAAA
----END RSA KEY ----";
rsaKey = rsaKey.Replace("\r\n", "\r");
var kvpAttribute = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("rsaKey", rsaKey);
```

At that point, I'd expect it to be fine. As an example proving that an `XAttribute` *can* work with just "\r":

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        var element = new XElement("foo", new XAttribute("key", "a\rb"));
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<foo key="a&#xD;b" />
```

That's the XML representation of an attribute value that contains a carriage return. If you were expecting:

```
<foo key="a
b" />
```

... then although it looks like that *is* valid XML (which surprised me) I believe it will actually be handled by a conformant XML reader as if it were:

```
<foo key="a b" />
```

So instead of maintaining the carriage returns, it looks like you might want to instead replace them with spaces:

```
rsaKey = rsaKey.Replace("\r\n", "\r").Replace("\r", " ");
```

Comment: This would still leave me with string "a&#xD;" which would then be read by the program that's reading the RSA key and reject it as it's incorrect. I need it to cleanly write it without anything there if that's possible.

Comment: @Dannys: But that's precisely *not* what your question asks. You've asked to maintain a carriage-return, which is represented in XML as `&#xD;`. It can't be just a carriage return in the XML, as that would be invalid XML. Are you sure you don't just want to remove both carriage returns and linefeeds entirely?

Comment: @Dannys: I've gone into this in a bit more detail at the end of my answer.

Comment: I specified that I want it to be formatted as in the KVP.

I've got two config files here to test with one which has the key on seperate lines as the KVP has and one with the KVP along one line. 

The one with the separate lines works fine and the one without them doesn't so I'm assuming that the XML is valid with the string on different lines. I just can't get my document to format it like this from code.

Comment: @Dannys: Hmm... I was always under the impression that attributes always had to be on a single line. Looks like that's incorrect, but any conformant XML parser *should* handle the entity version correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure what they're using to read the key, just trying to output it as is, might need to read into RSA key formating a bit more and see if there's any characters I can replace the \r\n with that will still make it valid

Comment: @Dannys: I've edited the answer - basically if they accept the version with a literal carriage return, but not the version with the entity, then you should report a bug as they're not handling XML properly. The simplest workaround is likely to be just rewriting the file yourself later, although it's awful that you have to do that. (I'd expect any decent program to handle CRLF instead of CR as well, but hey...)

Comment: @Dannys: Ooh, more interesting stuff - try using a space instead of a carriage return, as per the end of the (edited again) answer. It looks like a carriage return in the input text is guaranteed to be normalized to a single space, whereas `&#xD;` is preserved as a carriage-return. It may be that the program is actually capable of handling spaces but not carriage returns.

Comment: I'll give it a go